# Dodge Charger with Excalibur AL-1510-EDP security not starting with regular key

Tags: dodge, jump-start, security, ignition-key, remote-start

I own a Dodge Charger which is equipped with Excalibur AL-1510-EDP security system.

My car battery went dead couple of days back and when I jump started it, it stopped working with my regular key. However I am able to start the car with the security remote.

Is there any setting in my security system which have caused this failure?